# Oracle datapump metadata_filter

Tags: oracle, filter, metadata, datapump

In Oracle I want to export tables using dbms_datapump. I have a table containing a list of table names that I want to export a subset of, where the grp = 'batch1'. I want to loop through each of those table names and pass the table name over to the metadata_filter. However it's not working. I specifically want to do this in a loop.

Here are some extracts from the code:

```
CURSOR lib_cur IS
     SELECT table_name
                   FROM my_table_list
                   WHERE grp = 'batch1';
```

Later on in the code:

```
for x in lib_cur
    LOOP

     table_nm := x.table_name;

    dbms_datapump.metadata_filter          
    (handle      => my_job_handle,      
     name        => 'NAME_EXPR', 
     value       => 'IN (''' || table_nm || ''')' ,
     object_type => null);
```

Does anyone know why this isn't passing the current value of table_nm over to the value parameter of dbms_datapump.metadata_filter? If I hardcode one of the actual table names in that I want e.g. ''table1'' it works fine.

I know that my loop is bringing the correct table names into the table_nm variable as I've output them to dbms_output and can see that with each iteration of the loop comes a different table name.

So any ideas why the name isn't being passed across in my Loop? I don't know if the syntax is incorrect or if it's just not possible to do it this way? The thing is I'm sure I had it working a while ago!

Comment: Just checked, definitely no extra spaces

Comment: Are you replacing the `table_name` variable with `''table1''` exactly? or with `'table1'` ?  Lower or uppercase, and does that match what's in you `my_table_list` table? What is the datatype of the `table_name`  variable? varchar2 or char? Have you tried using `x.table_nm` in your concatenation instead of using a separate variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the filter each time in your loop. You want to provide the entire list at once. Try using `LISTAGG` to assemble a delimited list of tables into a single scalar variable that you can pass to the filter:

```
SELECT 'IN ('''||LISTAGG(table_name,''',''') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)||''')'
  INTO var_table_list
  FROM my_table_list
 WHERE grp = 'batch1';

 dbms_datapump.metadata_filter          
    (handle      => my_job_handle,      
     name        => 'NAME_EXPR', 
     value       => var_table_list,
     object_type => null);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. If I'm replacing the filter each time I go around the loop, should it not work at least once, in terms of it'll pick up the very last table that gets passed in and export that? Because it doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: @Reindeer, there's too much we cannot see to answer that. We can't see the contents of my_table_list, we can't compare the case sensitivity of the table names, and we can't inspect the actual results that you are interpreting as being incorrect. There very well may be something else afoot but there isn't enough debugging info to resolve it.  By the way, dbms_metadata is much harder to use than the OS command expdp. Is it essential that you drive this from PL/SQL rather than use the expdp utility?

Comment: True. I'm driving it from PL/SQL. I will abandon the idea of using a LOOP for now and just pass through the full list. That seems to work OK for now!

Comment: @Reindeer, that's the point of my answer, that a loop doesn't work. Every call overwrites the previous one.